# Make a phone call to a user without using a third party url - telegram chatbot

Tags: java, jhipster, telegram, telegram-bot, chatbot

I have a telegram chat bot implemented in java and jhipster with this API: [rubenlagus/TelegramBots](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots)

I want to add a functionality: **Make a phone call to a user without using [callMeBot](https://ifttt.com/callmebot) or similar. That is, making the call from code without using a third party url.**

Is there any way to do it?

It is not necessary for a message to be transmitted, it is enough for the phone to ring. The call can be through telegram or not. **The important thing is that the cell phone rings.**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to do it using pyrogram (a telegram client in python). Here's a GitHub link to the file.
https://github.com/MarshalX/tgcalls/blob/main/pytgcalls/test.py

You just have to setup pyrogram, using the quickstart guide
https://docs.pyrogram.org/intro/quickstart

Create an instance of the OutgoingCall class and pass in the pyrogram client and username as the parameter. This should make the phone ring. If you have further questions please feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: Here's a link to play audio files in a call.
https://github.com/bakatrouble/pytgvoip_pyrogram
From what I hear this implementation will soon stop working as Telegram is moving from VoIP to WebRTC