# How to make a voice call or video call using pytelegram-bot-api or alternative package in python?

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

**I am trying to make a video or voice call in telegram using pytelegram-bot-api !**

**i couldn't find a choice to make a call or video call inside the package !**

**how can i do it using python and any telegram Api ?**

i am looking at the attributes inside it but i can't found what i need .

this a sample of what i want :

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('API-key')

bot.send_message('Telegram id')

# I want something like this :

bot.make_voice_call('Telegram id')
```

Answer (score 1):

At present bots can't start video/voice calls, but there are some libraries such as [tgcalls](https://github.com/MarshalX/tgcalls) and [pytgcalls](https://github.com/pytgcalls/pytgcalls) were you can programmatically achieve it through a user.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, a bot can't call a telegram user.

Comment: is it possible to call a user from with user account instead of bot in python ?

Comment: If you automate the click of the mouse, I think so. Otherwise, I don't know any specific libraries that allow you to call a user within telegram

Comment: @MrDream It is possible with pyrogram and pytgcalls. Here's my answer on a similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72335362/11814361