# Telegram bot VOIP calls

Tags: voip, telebot

there is an option to make my telegram bot call my telegram account? Something like **bot.make_call(...)**.

I'm using telebot library on python,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Telegram bots cannot make calls to users. To call a user you need to logged in as a user and not a bot. You can use pyrogram (A telegram client).

Here's a link to my answer where I explain how it's done.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72335362/11814361